# Passing math equations as parameters to a looping function

Tags: shell-script, parameter

I want to run several jobs in parallel using the a script that does serial calls to a parameterized script and submits it as a background job on each call. It's for a brute force script which on each call will run 1k of 10k total combinations.

The following is my first hack at it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    ./tmp/tmpsky/bd25Par.sh (i*1000-1000) (i*1000) &
done
```

I want $1 to evaluate as 0,1000,2000 etc...and $2 to evaluate to 1000,2000,3000 etc.

The & is to submit the script as a background job. The called module will pass $1 and $2 to be used with seq as follows

```
#/bin/bash/
for n in $(seq $1 1 $2)
do
...`
```

The first script fails with 
`unexpected token 'i*1000-1000'`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This is what `parallel` is for.

Comment: @Theophrastus yes that seemed to work..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first script fails with `unexpected token 'i*1000-1000'`
>
> What have I done wrong?

The obvious error is that you are actually not calling the variable `$i` in your loop:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    ./tmp/tmpsky/bd25Par.sh (i*1000-1000) (i*1000) &
done
```

It should be:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    ./tmp/tmpsky/bd25Par.sh ($i*1000-1000) ($i*1000) &
done
```

Thus; use `$i` when using the variable. `i` in itself will not work.

As far as doing math in the shell, see comment number 2.